# Pig latin - Reading data from a file and storing it as tuple

Tags: apache-pig

Here is my setup - Pig - 0.10
Running mode - local
user - hadoop has root access

I have a file called 'data' with the following contents.
1 1 2 3
2 4 5 6
3 7 8 9
4 1 4 7
5 2 5 8

I am following the tutorial at - http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#tuple-schema
I am trying to read the file such that first number in each line is read as integer and rest 3 form a tuple. I am using this code - 
a = load 'data' as (f1:int, f2:tuple(t1:int, t2:int, t3:int));
But when I do 'dump a', I get -
(1,)
(2,)
(3,)
(4,)
(5,)

It looks exactly the same as the tutorial. But the output something totally unexpected. 
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your input data looks more like first example from your link, just one continuous row. If you take a look at the second example: [(3,8,9) (mary,19)] there are parenthesis which mark the tuples

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be done entirely in the load statement, however a pair of statements could probably do this without too much trouble. try the following code:

```
A = load 'data' USING PigStorage(' ') AS (f1: int, f2: int, f3: int, f4: int);
B = Foreach A Generate f1, TOTUPLE(f2,f3,f4);
dump B;
```

When I tested this, it produced the output: `(1,(1,2,3))`, which appears to be your goal.

edit: remember to replace 'data' with the correct filepath to your data in your hdfs